# How to output the rows from a SQL table as expanded on a day basis using a start date and end date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have a table named `StayInfo`.

It has the following structure (extract):

```
Name    ArrDate        DepDate       ID
A       2016-03-29     2016-04-02    100
B       2016-05-10     2016-05-12    250
```

I want the following output from T-SQL query:

```
Name    Date          ID
A       2016-03-29   100
A       2016-03-30   100 
A       2016-03-31   100
A       2016-04-01   100
A       2016-04-03   100
B       2016-05-10   250
B       2016-05-11   250
B       2016-05-12   250
```

The main difficulty I am facing with this is the SQL code needed to perform the split on a day basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is an an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a Cross Apply

**Example**

```
Select A.Name
      ,B.Date
      ,A.ID
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,A.[ArrDate],A.[DepDate])+1) Date=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),A.[ArrDate])  
                From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Date        ID
A       2016-03-29  100
A       2016-03-30  100
A       2016-03-31  100
A       2016-04-01  100
A       2016-04-02  100
B       2016-05-10  250
B       2016-05-11  250
B       2016-05-12  250
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution a lot!

Comment: @user3115933 Thanks!  Meee tooo!  :)

Comment: @user3115933 fyi - not that it makes any differance, but if you date spans won't exceed 6 years, you can remove   ..  ,master..spt_values n2

Answer (score 6):

You can use a recursive CTE or numbers table:

```
with cte as (
      select Name, ArrDate, DepDate, ID
      from t
      union all
      select Name, dateadd(day, 1, ArrDate), DepDate, ID
      from cte
      where ArrDate < DepDate
     )
select Name, ArrDate, ID
from cte;
```

You can set the max recursion option if you have spans of more than 100 days.

Comment: Thanks. I am having an issue with the codes you proposed. When I run it, it is adding 1 day to the DepDate and thus, I am having an additional row. If my DepDate is '2016-04-02', it is giving me an additional row with '2016-04-03' in the ArrDate column.

Comment: @user3115933 . . . I must've misread your original question, because I really thought that was what you wanted to do.  It is easily fixed by changing the `<=` to `<`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

You can generate an adhoc tables of dates using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20160101'
declare @thrudate date = '20171231'
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                 cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select t.Name, d.Date, t.Id
from t
  inner join dates d
    on d.date >= t.arrdate
   and d.date <= t.depdate
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WCM12325

returns:

```
+------+------------+-----+
| Name |    Date    | Id  |
+------+------------+-----+
| A    | 2016-03-29 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-03-30 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-03-31 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-04-01 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-04-02 | 100 |
| B    | 2016-05-10 | 250 |
| B    | 2016-05-11 | 250 |
| B    | 2016-05-12 | 250 |
+------+------------+-----+
```

---

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK  cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date on dbo.Dates([Date]);
/* query */
select t.Name, d.Date, t.Id
from t
  inner join dates d
    on d.date >= t.arrdate
   and d.date <= t.depdate
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WCM12325

returns:

```
+------+------------+-----+
| Name |    Date    | Id  |
+------+------------+-----+
| A    | 2016-03-29 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-03-30 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-03-31 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-04-01 | 100 |
| A    | 2016-04-02 | 100 |
| B    | 2016-05-10 | 250 |
| B    | 2016-05-11 | 250 |
| B    | 2016-05-12 | 250 |
+------+------------+-----+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)